# recursion compilation error in Standard ML

Tags: functional-programming, sml

I am making a function that recurses over a string and replaces each instance of a user-specified character. However, I get a compilation error of :

```
Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
  operator domain: string * string
  operand:         char * 'Z
```

I would like to know what this error means for my program and what I could be doing wrong. I'm new to SML and have been trying to research this for some time now. Thanks.

This is my code:

```
fun remCharR(expr, letter) = 
    if String.sub(expr, 0) = letter 
    then remCharR(String.substring(expr, 0, 1), letter)
    else String.sub(expr, 0) ^ remCharR(String.substring(expr, 0, 1), letter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` operator needs two `string` operands and the first operator in `String.sub(expr, 0) ^ remCharR(String.substring(expr, 0, 1), letter)` is of type `char`.  To fix this error, change `String.sub(expr, 0)` to `String.substring(expr, 0, 1)`.

Comment: this is great! however, is there a reason this function is not printing when I call it?

Comment: If the intention is to remove every instance of `letter` in `expr`, then you need to accumulate the non-`letter` characters, make sure `String.substring(expr, 0, 1)` is indeed resulting in the tail-part of the expr, and return the accumulated characters when the termination/anchor condition of the recursion is met.  BTW, you could consider using `foldr` or `foldl` to accomplish this -- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fold_%28higher-order_function%29.

Comment: Or `String.translate`. Since every `char` corresponds to 0 or 1 `char`s in the result, this would also fit into the functional pattern of a "concat-map", except monomorphic (pertaining only to `char`s in `string`s).

Answer (score 0):

> I am making a function that recurses over a string and replaces each instance of a user-specified character.

A function that corresponds to this description is `String.map`. Example:

```
- String.map (fn c => if c = #"l" then #"k" else c) "hello";
> val it = "hekko" : string
```

Since this function can't remove characters, this suggests that "replace" is an ambiguous word.

> I would like to know what this error means for my program and what I could be doing wrong.
>
> ```
> Error: operator and operand do not agree [tycon mismatch]
> operator domain: string * string
> operand:         char * 'Z
> ```

Venkatesh-Prasad Ranganath already answered this and showed how to fix it.

So instead I will show an alternative way to implement this.

> This is my code:
>
> ```
> fun remCharR(expr, letter) = 
>    if String.sub(expr, 0) = letter 
>    then remCharR(String.substring(expr, 0, 1), letter)
>    else String.sub(expr, 0) ^ remCharR(String.substring(expr, 0, 1), letter);
> ```

Since the sole task of this function appears to remove characters, use `String.translate`:

```
fun remChar (c1, s) =
    String.translate (fn c2 => if c1 = c2 then "" else str c2) s
```